# Encode effect in terms of another with freer extensible effects

Tags: haskell, effect-systems

I have been playing around with [“freer monads” and extensible effects](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/), implemented in the [freer-effects](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer-effects) package, and I’ve run into a problem that seems feasible but I’m having trouble solving.

I’ve written a type that represents simple interactions with a file system:

```
data FileSystem v where
  ReadFile :: FilePath -> FileSystem String
  WriteFile :: FilePath -> String -> FileSystem ()
```

Writing an interpreter for this in `IO` is easy, but boring. What I’m really interested in doing is writing a pure interpreter that uses `State` internally. I *could* effectively inline the implementation of `runState` into my interpreter for `FileSystem`, but that seems like it would sort of defeat the purpose. What I’d *really* like to be able to do is write a transformation between these two types, then reuse the `State` interpreter.

Writing such a transformation is straightforward:

```
fsAsState :: forall v r. FileSystem v -> Eff (State [(FilePath, String)] ': r) v
fsAsState (ReadFile a) = (lookup a <$> get) >>=
  maybe (fail "readFile: file does not exist") return
fsAsState (WriteFile a b) = modify $ \fs ->
  (a, b) : filter ((/= a) . fst) fs
```

Now I want a generic `reencode` function that can accept my `fsAsState` transformation and use it to interpret my `FileSystem` by reusing the `State` interpreter. With such a function, I would be able to write the following interpreter:

```
runInMemoryFS :: forall r w. [(FilePath, String)] -> Eff (FileSystem ': r) w -> Eff r (w, [(FilePath, String)])
runInMemoryFS fs m = runState (reencode fsAsState m) fs
```

The tricky thing is actually implementing `reencode`. I’ve gotten something that *almost* typechecks:

```
reencode :: forall r w f g. (forall v. f v -> Eff (g ': r) v) -> Eff (f ': r) w -> Eff (g ': r) w
reencode f m = loop m
  where
    loop :: Eff (f ': r) w -> Eff (g ': r) w
    loop (Val x) = return x
    loop (E u q) = case decomp u of
      Right x -> qComp q loop =<< f x
      Left u' -> E (weaken u') undefined
```

Unfortunately, I can’t figure out how to provide the second argument to `E` in the final case of `loop`. I don’t think I understand the implementation details of how the optimized `FTCQueue` type works in order to understand if there’s something I need to do here that is simple, or if what I’m doing is just impossible.

Is this possible? If the answer is no, and it turns out that what I’m doing *is*, in fact, impossible, I would be interested in an explanation to help me understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: the below typechecks but I haven't tried running it.

You need to walk `q` (from the `E u q` pattern match) and shift all its steps from `Eff (f ': r)` to `Eff (g ': r)`. We can write this traversal polymorphically:

```
shiftQ :: forall m n a b. (forall a. m a -> n a) -> FTCQueue m a b -> FTCQueue n a b
shiftQ shift q = case tviewl q of
    TOne act -> tsingleton (shift . act)
    act :| q -> go (tsingleton (shift . act)) q
  where
    go :: forall a b c. FTCQueue n a b -> FTCQueue m b c -> FTCQueue n a c
    go q' q = case tviewl q of
        TOne act -> q' |> (shift . act)
        act :| q -> go (q' |> (shift . act)) q
```

(it's a bit awkward because we can only snoc and only uncons `FTCQueue`s).

and then we can use it in `reencode` by passing `reencode f` itself as the `shift`er:

```
reencode :: forall r w f g. (forall v. f v -> Eff (g ': r) v) -> Eff (f ': r) w -> Eff (g ': r) w
reencode f m = loop m
  where
    loop :: Eff (f ': r) w -> Eff (g ': r) w
    loop (Val x) = return x
    loop (E u q) = case decomp u of
      Right x -> qComp q loop =<< f x
      Left u' -> E (weaken u') (shiftQ (reencode f) q)
```

Comment: Indeed, this does seem to work, but it’s a lot uglier than I expected. I’m now a little worried—should I take the difficulty of this as an indication that I’m “using freer wrong”? Or is this just the complexity cost we must currently pay for performant extensible effects?

Comment: I have no idea -- I was just following the types. I haven't used Freer or freer-effects at all.